# Extracting versionCode from AndroidManifest in PowerShell

Tags: bash, powershell

I have a bash shell script that works perfectly fine for extracting the `versionCode` and `versionName` from an `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Problem is I need this to run on a Windows machine (which doesn't have the Ubuntu on Windows bash support added). I know roughly nothing about PowerShell, and am not having much luck in converting this.

Can anyone help out with a PowerShell version of this:

```
VERSION_CODE=`grep versionCode ./app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/dev/release/AndroidManifest.xml | sed -e 's/.*versionCode\s*=\s*\"\([0-9.]*\)\".*/\1/g'`
echo $VERSION_CODE
VERSION_NAME=`grep versionName ./app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/dev/release/AndroidManifest.xml | sed -e 's/.*versionName\s*=\s*\"\([0-9.]*\)\".*/\1/g'`
echo $VERSION_NAME
```

Comment: PowerShell can read XML files, but not without the XML. Not that I can guarantee to solve your problem with it, but having it might help someone...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to edit my comment, but it didn't work so well... Anyway, I found a AndroidManifest.xml online here: https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicContactables/AndroidManifest.html. With that copied into a text editor and it saved as an .xml file on my Desktop, I wrote these options to return the versionCode:

```
([xml](Get-Content -Path .\Desktop\AndroidManifest.xml)).manifest.versionCode
```

If you wanted to use a variable, you could do it like the below example. That said, you could just assign the above command to a variable, too.

```
[xml]$XML = Get-Content -Path .\Desktop\AndroidManifest.xml
$XML.manifest.versionCode
```

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly, and reading the XML seems a lot less hacky than extracting strings. Thanks!

Comment: That's why PowerShell is so great. You're dealing with the properties of objects, and so the need to parse text, is at a minimum.